# How console log element value during map() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I create an another array with Array.prototype.map(). How can I console log x value(the current element being processed in the array) during the map function?

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map((x) => x * 2);
```

Comment: Use {} to create a block, instead of doing an implicit return `=>`

Comment: Don't use arrow functions if you don't know how they work: [MDN: Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: @PsyGik _"Use {} to create a closure"_ - That's a block and not a "closure"

Comment: I get -1 but my qestion but have legitimate. My question is very clear. For my aspect have resarch and effort, and answer for me was super useful. Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, thank you again. Somebody else also give me +1 and other senior also answer for me but ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this:

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map(function(x){
   console.log(x);
   return x* 2;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `console.log` in a `map` like this:

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map((x) => {
  console.log(x);
  return x * 2;
});
```

You are using a shorthand `return`:

`() => x` returns `x` just as
`() => { return x; }`.

But since you are not *only* returning something
you can not use the concise arrow function syntax.

Comment: Thank you everebody! This code missing an ")" character

Answer (score 1):

Use `{}` to create a block

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map((x) => {
  console.log(x)
  return x * 2
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print it like below.

```
array1.map(function(x) {
      console.log(x*2);
      return x * 2
});
```

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];
const map1 = array1.map(function(x) {
      console.log(x*2);
      return x * 2
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array:

```js
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

console.log('Mapping array1...');
const map1 = array1.map((x) => [x * 2, console.log(x)][0]);
console.log('Maped successfully, map1 =', map1);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work fine but I don't understand the syntax. How can I find description about this? I yet searched on MDN.

Comment: @MilánNikolics It would be better to use normal block `function`s instead of arrow functions, since you can have multiple commands and stuff. But if you **need** to use arrow functions, this may be an option. It creates an array with two elements: `x * 2`, which is what you want to return, and a `console.log` statement, which logs `x` and returns `undefined`. Then, the arrow function returns the first element of the array with `[0]`, which contains `x * 2`, ignoring the `undefined` returned by the `console.log`.